# How do I plot grouped data sorted by the number of entries in each group, in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have data that look like this sample here: http://pastebin.com/5MPCFGWK

I need to plot each `id` as a timeline, thus I do something like this.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=relative_timestamp, y=id, color=action))
```

which kind of works, except that it's not the most helpful chart. I figured I'd try to sort the groups by how many events they have, but I can't figure out how. I tried my hand at `dplyr` but I got confused with the docs, and barely managed to group the dataframe by `id`. Ideas?

**EDIT** I added a sample CSV. My goal is to plot those timelines sorted by how many entries they have, so in this case 0 is the one with the least amount, and 1 is the one with the biggest amount. Extra good would be to plot them (separate plot, not the same as above) sorted by the time the last CLOSE action occurs (there should be exactly one in each group anyway).

Comment: Please make your example reproducible so it's easier for others to help you

Comment: `o <- count(df, action, sort = TRUE); df$action <- factor(df$action, levels = o$action)` then plot

Comment: most likely you want to do something like aes(x=relative_timestamp, y=as.numeric(action), color=id) - this simple instance would use some arbitrary numeric coding of your action states. Ideally enrich your question a little as suggested by @Sotos

Comment: Thanks, see if the CSV in the pastebin helps.

Comment: @Axeman Ah, no, I did not mean how many of those distinct actions are there, but by how many rows a certain `id` is associated with. The CSV I added should clarify. So, each `id` represents a "session", in each session, a user may have done any number of different actions. I want to plot sessions on single lines, with dots of different colours to represent each different action, at the times these actions happened. See if this helps https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CtmPN3yXYAATwOG.png:large

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to convert `id` from numeric to a factor, and then order those factors by whatever metric you are interested in. Here, I used `dplyr` to create a data.frame called `forSort` that holds the id's and a set of things you might want to sort on:

```
forSort <-
  testDF %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(n = n()
            , max = max(relative_timestamp)) 

forSort

#      id     n    max
# 1     0    12 244753
# 2     1    85 447680
# 3     2    22 156005
```

By number of actions:

```
ggplot(testDF %>%
         mutate(id = factor(id, levels = forSort$id[order(forSort$n)]))
       , aes(x=relative_timestamp
             , y= id
             , color=action)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

By time of last action:

```
ggplot(testDF %>%
         mutate(id = factor(id, levels = forSort$id[order(forSort$max)]) )
       , aes(x=relative_timestamp
             , y= id
             , color=action)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]